# How to generate/retain javadocs for one module that is built with two maven profiles?

Tags: maven, javadoc, profiles

I have two maven profiles. Each profile generates javadocs for one module. Is there a way by which I can edit the apidocs/index.html page to allow to retain the classes generated by one profile and append the new classes generated by other profile? Right now I can generate the javadocs for individual profile builds but cannot retain the older classes when we build the project with the second profile as it overrides the earlier apidocs.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the outputDirectory property of maven javadoc plugin, to set it to a different location for each profile.
See: 
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-no-fork-mojo.html#outputDirectory